# Error converting double attribute from csv file into java double. Apache Flink

Tags: java, csv, type-conversion, apache-flink

I try to convert a column (named `result`) from a csv file into a double datatype in Java Apache Flink. An example of this column value in the CSV file is: `123,456`. This column has max 3 numbers before and after the comma. I use for this the TableSource class. I keep getting the error below:
`Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Parsing error for column 2 of row '5182; 57,01' originated by DoubleParser: NUMERIC_VALUE_FORMAT_ERROR.`

I already tried to replace the "," with a "." as u can see in the code below. But the below code does not replace the "," with a ".".

```
ExecutionEnvironment fbEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
 BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = BatchTableEnvironment.create(fbEnv);

//CSV file to Tablesource
TableSource csvSource = CsvTableSource.builder()
                .path("path")
                .fieldDelimiter(";")
                .field("ID", Types.INT())
                .field("result".replace(",", "."), Types.DOUBLE())
                .build();

// register the TableSource 
        tableEnv.registerTableSource("HTable", csvSource);

        Table HTable = tableEnv.scan("HTable");


        DataSet<Row> result = tableEnv.toDataSet(HTable, Row.class);

//Print table
 try {
            result.print();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Here `.field("result".replace(",", "."), Types.DOUBLE())` you're doing a replace on the string "result" not on your csv row

Comment: U are right Imaguest. U know how to do this?

Comment: I've never used CsvTableSource. I don't know if it allows you to format a specific field. I searched a bit on internet and I did not find any examples doing this. I suggest to you to get the field as a String (Types.STRING()) and convert it later.

Comment: Or update your CSV file to have the right double format (if it's possible)

Comment: Thank u for your help. I imported it as a string.

Comment: Have you tried running this with the default locale set to France? That might do the trick. Or it might cause other problems. :)